# Cross-Origin Request Blocked en Node y Angular

Tags: nodejs, angular

al querer abrir mi aplicacion web me aparece en la consola el error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/questions. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Funciona bien en mi otro sistema operativo (W7) que tengo en dual boot, pero en linux mint no me aparecen las consultas. Uso la misma carpeta de proyecto, les dejo el archivo app.js

```js
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser' // leer los datos que vengan con el request desde el frontend
import { question, auth } from './routes'

const app = express()

//leer la parte del request
  app.use(bodyParser.json())
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
//

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { // pedir que otro sitio pida recursos en modo de desarrollo
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Request-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    next()
  })
}

app.use('/api/questions', question)
app.use('/api/auth', auth)

export default app
```

Comment: Por favor, sustituye la imagen por el código en texto: es más legible, se podrá copiar y pegar para hacer pruebas o añadirlo en una posible respuesta... Las imágenes no ayudan y no se ven apenas desde un móvil

Comment: has inspeccionado los headers de la respuesta? Podrías probar fijando los headers con `res.header()`  en vez de `res.setHeader()` (aunque debieran hacer lo mismo) ¿Te consta que NODE_ENV es 'development'?

Comment: Tienes razón @amenadiel borro la respuesta. ;)

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso usando el sistema operativo en windows 7, sucedió que cuando el navegador no tenia el plugin de **COORS**, no me permitia obetener informacion del backend. Cuando agregue el COORS en el navegador, al hacer peticiones desde la aplicación de Angular-cli obtenía la informacion que necesitaba, sin necesidad de configurar en el `app.js` o archivo donde se configura el servidor para recibir peticiones desde mi aplicación con angular-cli.

[image: captura de la extension para el COORS]

Ahora bien, según lo que he visto, si un proyecto con angular-cli y node se quiere desplegar en un servidor, no es recomendado hacerlo de esa manera.